# Why is the Export to PKSC12 for X509Certificate required in Windows (.Net 5) ? Possible side effect of X509.Export operation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In a .NET 5 Asp.NetCore app (REST API) I need to call some public REST API requiring a client certificate.

Following code is not working on my local WindowsMachine (in docker container with Linux image (mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-buster-slim) everything is fine) for loading the certificate:

```
...X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(
            this.certificateSource.PemFilePath,
            this.certificateSource.PemKeyFilePath);
```

It always results in following exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x8009030E): No credentials are available in the security package
   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(ISSPIInterface secModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SCH_CREDENTIALS* scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SCH_CREDENTIALS* secureCredential)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandleSchCredentials(X509Certificate certificate, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy, Boolean isServer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SslStreamCertificateContext certificateContext, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy, Boolean isServer)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& output)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(ReadOnlySpan`1 incomingBuffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessBlob(Int32 frameSize)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at asw.b2b.lugas.api.Controllers.PlayersController.CreatePlayer(Player player) in C:\sources\asw.b2b.lugas.api\asw.b2b.lugas.api\Controllers\PlayersController.cs:line 50
   at lambda_method4(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Only when I am converting the certificate to Pkcs12 format via the Export method it works fine (under Windows on my local machine):

```
new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(
        this.certificateSource.PemFilePath,
        this.certificateSource.PemKeyFilePath).Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12));
```

I tried to see the difference of the certificates (instances of X509Certificate2) but I could not figure them out. All properties and even the private fields are equal. I failed writing a Unit Test assuring the export of the Pkcs12 format because I don't know how to assert.

Has anyone an idea what the reason is for this difference between Linux and Windows and why I cannot see any difference in the instances at all. At the moment I am suspecting some side effect of the Export operation.

Comment: Is certificate created has a private key? You can check it via its property `HasPrivateKey`

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: There is a need to fix the Schannel implementation as reported here. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45680   The problem still persists in .Net 6.